# ¿Porque file upload no muestra el nombre de archivo?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

Hola a todos espero me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema ya que no entiendo el por que no funciona de antemano gracias por su ayuda y tiempo.

Tengo una modal y dentro de la modal tengo un fileUpload con boostrap 4 para cargar archivos, pero al dar clic al fileUpload este no muestra el nombre del archivo. ¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?

Aquí publico mi código espero me puedan ayudar gracias.

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="btnAbrirModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      
      <div class="custom-file">                                   
        <input type="file" id="fuSubirExcel"  class="custom-file-input" accept=".xlsx" />                    
        <label id="lblArchivo" class="custom-file-label" for="fuSubirExcel"></label> 
       </div> 
       
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Mi codigo javaScript lo tengo en un archivo aparte de tipo javascript, este archivo esta referenciado a mi pagina maestra.

```
$("#fuSubirExcel").on('change', function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);        

})
```

Espero me puedan ayudar ya que aun no he podido obtener el nombre del archivo a subir.

Gracias.

Comment: Podrian actaulizar el archivo. Yo tambien tengo el.mismo problema. No me sale el nombre del archivo cuando lo selecciono.. pero si aparece en el tooltips cuando paso el mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tienes mal escrito el ID en el HTML.

Cambialo por:

```
<input type="file" id="fuSubirExcel"  class="custom-file-input" accept=".xlsx" />
```

Comment: Hola @RenzoTelenta ya lo modifique y aun así sigue sin mostrarme el nombre del archivo en mi aplicación. No se a que se deba este problema.

Comment: Puedes validar tu codigo con el de este enlace?. Yo cambie el ID y me funciono.
https://codepen.io/renzo-brian-telenta-visconte/pen/xoqzYj

Comment: Hola @Renzo Telenta gracias por tu ayuda la verdad solo me faltaba colocar document ready en mi archivo js ya que este es un archivo externo de cualquier forma muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Un gusto haber ayudado :)

Answer (score 0):

Anibal tillero, este seria el codigo completo.

```js
//codigo jquery
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#fuSubirExcel").on('change', function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);        
})

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button type="btnAbrirModal" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Open modal
</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
      
      <div class="custom-file">                                   
        <input type="file" id="fuSubirExcel"  class="custom-file-input" accept=".xlsx" />                    
        <label id="lblArchivo" class="custom-file-label" for="fuSubirExcel"></label> 
       </div> 
       
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```